# How to empty out a list without destroying its elements?

Tags: c++

I have a list of points, not pointers to points, that I need to empty without destroying the elements. Here's what I have to do: I iterate through all of the points in `clipped`, and if they meet a certain criteria, I add them to `temp`. If they dont, I may or may not do some function to generate another point, which is then added to `temp`. After all the points in `clipped` have been processed, I then empty out `clipped`, add the elements from `temp` to it, and then execute the loop again, 4 times in total. My problem is: how do I empty out `clipped` without affecting the points in `temp`? *Are* these points even destroyed if I simply do `clipped->clear()`? This function will be called many times, so if I simply do `clipped = new std::list<point>()` will I end up with a memory leak/stack overflow?

Point is a struct containing 3 ints: x, y and z;

Comment: some code please. show the usage, expected behaviour with code.

Comment: _" that I need to empty without destroying the elements. "_ What's the side effect on _destroying the elements_ you actually wan't to avoid to? Or is it just about you need a copy of the information?

Comment: _"will I end up with a memory leak/stack overflow"_ Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: @tuple_cat: trying out something that leaks memory doesn't often lead to someone realising their mistake, short term ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a point to a `std::list<point>` will make a *copy*. So yes, clearing `clipped` will destroy it's points, it will not destroy the copies you keep in `temp`. You can proceed exactly as planned.